# Jupyter notebook is not showing any files?

Tags: python

I was working on jupyter an hour back but now suddenly it has started showing no files when I first run jupyter.

[image]

I have made sure that its in my main directory where all my jupyter files are. 
Kindly help me

[image]

Comment: Could also show us the content of the directory you started jupyter notebook? and the command you use to start it?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your jupyter notebook version is over 6.

   - Downgrade the version (5.7.5)
2. your jupyter notebook has authority of get list of files

   - if not, then open run jupyter notebook as administrator

It may causes a lots of different jupyter notebook error.
I'm sorry for not to give you a accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my answer in case someone else encounters same problem. The path of my file was too long, and the file appeared as soon as I reduced the length of the file's name.